# Consulta Invertida en INNER JOIN vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hola a todos presento el siguiente inconveniente debo insertar dos registros "Departamento" y "Ciudad" en dos campos diferentes de una misma tabla, estos registros provienen de dos Combobox uno que muestra los departamentos y relacionado a ese departamento se muestran los municipios correspondientes, estoy implementado esto por medio de un formulario en Access. En el Combobox Departamentos se muestran correctamente pero al guardar se guarda el Id y no el nombre, luego de seleccionar dicho departamento el siguiente Combobox se listan solo algunos "departamento_Id" de la tabla "municipios", y al momento de guardar se guarda el "Nombre del Municipio" relacionado a este "Departamento_id" de la tabla municipios. Esta consulta la estoy haciendo con un INNER JOIN, para poder almacenar el "Nombre del Departamento" y el "Nombre del Municipio"

```
Dim Sql As String


Sql = "INSERT INTO Entidades(Nombre,Direccion,Nit,Telefono,Correo,RUC,RubroEconomico,Departamento,Ciudad)" _
        & " VALUES('" & Me.txt_Nombre & "','" & Me.txt_Direccion & "','" & Me.txt_Nit & "','" & Me.txt_Telefono & "','" & Me.txt_Correo & "','" & Me.txt_RUC & "','" & Me.txt_Sector & "','" & Me.cbx_departamentos & "','" & Me.cbx_municipios & "')"
        
DoCmd.RunSQL Sql
End Sub



Private Sub Form_Load()
With Me.cbx_departamentos
.ColumnCount = 2
.ColumnWidths = 0
.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM departamentos ORDER BY departamento ASC"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub cbx_departamentos_AfterUpdate()
With Me.cbx_municipios
.ColumnCount = 2
.ColumnWidths = 0

'***********Inner Join que presenta el problema o no se si sera en el INSERT?

.RowSource = "SELECT municipio, departamento_id" _
             & " FROM departamentos INNER JOIN municipios" _
             & " ON departamentos.id_departamento = municipios.id_municipio" _
             & " ORDER BY municipio"
             
'.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE departamento_id Like '*" & Me.cbx_departamentos & "*' ORDER BY municipio ASC"

End With
Me.cbx_municipios = ""

End Sub
```

***************************Tablas Departamentos Municipios****************

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**************Tabla donde se hace el INSERT***********
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

************fORMULARIO****************

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

la estructura de una sentencia con INNER JOIN, es "SELECT camposBuscados FROM tablaUno INNER JOIN tablaDos ON tablaUno.idTablaDos = tablaDos.id",
basicamente la tablaUno tiene una clave foranea que enlaza a la tablaDos, entonces  yo entendi que basicamente si seleccionas un departamento en el cbx_departamentos te debe devolver la lista de municipios que corresponden a ese departamento, entonces puede que tu inner join quede asi:

```
"SELECT m.municipio _
             & " FROM municipios m INNER JOIN departamentos d" _
             & " ON m.departamento_id = d.id_departamento" _
             & " AND d.id_departamento ='ID DEL DEPARTAMENTO SELECCINADO' "
```

la ultima linea esta para que se consulte en el departamento seleccionado, ya que si no lo pones te va a listar todos los municipios en general.
espero que te ayude y te dejo un enlace en donde puedes leer mas acerca de INNER JOIN https://www.ionos.mx/digitalguide/hosting/cuestiones-tecnicas/inner-join/

Comment: Hola, he escrito todo tal y como lo sugeriste pero sale un error en el Join, no me indica en que línea es.